# Assigning a 2d array pointer parameter to a local array pointer variable

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

I am a little bit confused about how to assign a 2d array pointer parameter to a local 2d array pointer variable. Check the code below.

```
#define N   5
#define M   6

void print(int (*arr)[M][N]) {

    int *localArr[M][N];

    localArr = arr;  //error C3863: array type 'int *[6][5]' is not assignable
    //localArr[0][0] =1; and so on.
}

int main()
{

    int Array1[M][N];
    print(&Array1);         
}
```

Comment: Look at the declared type of `arr` and declared type of `localArr`. See any difference?

Comment: `arr` and `localArr` have different types. `arr` is a pointer to an array of arrays of `int`, while `localArr` is an array or arrays of pointers to `int`.

Comment: Think parenthesis...

Comment: Thanks, any other optimum way to do this? Speeding is critical in my case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you sketch the two arrays to visualize them? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the local declaration has to be like this way,

```
 int (*localArr)[M][N]; //pointer to an MxN array
 //int * localArr[m][N];//An MxN array of pointer to int
```

Comment: Hi thanks, i will check it tomorrow. Can you suggest an easier or optimal way to pass a 2d array to a local function variable? I don't like the idea with offsets calculations..

Comment: I think pointer to array is the right approach if you know the exact size(M & N) because the compiler knows the size and catch errors if any during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? If you just want to print your 2d array then why don't you use this approach?

```
void print(int localArr[M][N]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << localArr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

If there are some constraints then Nitheesh is right!

Comment: localArr is actually a class variable that  is used from many methods.

Answer (score 0):

If we change the sizes to make it easier to fit:

```
#define M 2
#define N 3
```

Then somewhat graphically the variable `arr` is something like this:

```
+-----+      +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| arr | ---> | [0][0] | [0][1] | [0][2] | [1][0] | [1][1] | [1][2] |
+-----+      +--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

`arr` is a pointer. It points to an array of arrays, where each element is an `int`.

That means you can dereference `arr` to get what it points to, and then use array indexing on that to get an `int` value:

```
int value = (*arr)[0][1];
```

Now if we take `localArr` instead, it's more like

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| localArr[0][0] | localArr[0][1] | localArr[0][2] | localArr[1][0] | localArr[1][1] | localArr[1][2] |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

`localArr` is an array of arrays, where each element is a `int *`.

So you need an `int *` to get a single element:

```
int *pointer = localArr[0][1];
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will play with them tommorow, to find what is best for my needs.

Comment: What I really wanted from the beginning is to pass the memory address (pointer) of the array. So, I believe, the arr declaration is the right choice as NitheeshGeorge suggested.

Comment: @Maverick Personally I would rather use `std::array` instead, and if possible use references instead of pointers.